# How do I synchronize SPI DMA transfers to an external ADC using STM32

Tags: stm32, adc, spi, dma

I am trying to receive data continuously from an ADC using an STM32G4 microcontroller. The ADC has an independent clock, free running from the MCU, and indicates data ready with a DRDY pulse. 18 bytes of data must be clocked out over SPI before the next DRDY pulse indicating that the next frame is ready.

One solution is to interrupt on the DRDY and initial an 18-byte SPI Rx transaction, manually pulling the CS low. In the SPI DMA complete callback I must bring CS high and move the data out of the SPI buffer before the next event. At >1kHz sample rate there are a lot of interrupts happening and this process does not feel very efficient since I only need to process data in blocks of roughly 100 samples.

It seems like I should be able to attach the SPI DMA transfer to the DRDY event (GPIO_EXTI4 interrupt) so that it triggers on its own and continuously fills a buffer with ADC samples. However, I cannot find any good documentation this use case of the DMAMUX peripheral. How would I configure the SPI DMA transfer to autonomously fill a large circular buffer and only interrupt the CPU when the buffer is half full? Is there any way to get the GPIO-based chip select to strobe correctly for each frame in this case?

My specific hardware are the STM32G491C and ADS131B04 ADC.

Comment: What is the DRDY overall frequency?

Comment: @ErikFriesen DRDY pulses at 2048Hz and the MCU is clocked at 48MHz.

Comment: Do you have to change the cs no matter what?

Comment: The datasheet shows CS used in every example, but it doesn't seem to be strictly required. So yes, I could probably hold it low all the time.

Comment: Page 427 of the data sheet shows options for exti triggers. Have you tried using that as a trigger?  You might have to fiddle with it to get it to work. My opinion is that it’s easier not using Hal. Maybe you should add the code you are trying for reference.

Comment: Interrupt performance on the stm32 m4 is good, I’m not sure the gain on this will be worth the pain. Is there a good reason the mcu is only clocked at 48 mhz?

Comment: You are probably about it not being worth the pain. It does look like the DMA can sync to an external trigger, but I can't find any examples of how this works so thought I'd ask here and see if I missed something.